# Error on android.support.v4.view.ViewPager and android.support.v7.widget.CardView tags on layout XML file

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-xml, android-cardview

I'm a new developer. When writing a layout XML file, I got error on lines related to `android.support.v4.view.ViewPager` and `android.support.v7.widget.CardView`. How to fix this?

Here's the XML content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".Activities.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager          ---------------error and red
        android:id="@+id/v_pager1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top">

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llayout"
        android:layout_below="@+id/v_pager1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Subjects"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainGrid"
        android:columnCount="3"
        android:rowCount="2"
        android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
        android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="90dp"
        android:padding="14dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView              --------------error and red
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:background="@layout/item_layout"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:src="@mipmap/pic1"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Maths"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView                --------------error and red
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:background="@layout/item_layout"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:src="@mipmap/pic2"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:text="Science"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView                         --------------error and red
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:background="@layout/item_layout"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:src="@mipmap/pic3"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:text="English"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView                     --------------error and red
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:background="@layout/item_layout"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:src="@mipmap/pic4"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:text="Social Studies"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView               --------------error and red
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:background="@layout/item_layout"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:src="@mipmap/pic5"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Hindi"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


    </GridLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: See my answer below. Additionally, I would highly recommend you spend some time on topics that interest you from "**Android Developer Fundamentals Course**" at https://codelabs.developers.google.com/android-training/

Answer (score 3):

These kinds of error may happen if you don't have the dependency added to `build.gradle`.

Take a look at the tutorial https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/cardview it mentions you must have the following dependency to use `<android.support.v7.widget.CardView>`

```
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
```

Similarly, other views are likely from Support AppCompat (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features#v7)

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
```

Once you add these, on the android studio click on Sync Gradle to update the library, the red underlines should go away.

---

**However,** support library is deprecated, you should use AndroidX that is recommended and supported by Google. See more at https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx